# this.setState() in callback of this.setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

Can I explicitly call `this.setState()` in the definition of the callback passed to `this.setState()?`

```
this.setState(
 {
   openA:true 
 }, 
 () => {
   this.setState({
     openB: false
   })
 } 
)
```

Comment: You can but likely shouldn't. Why do you think you need this?

Comment: No requirement, needs to know if we can do this. there will be 2 re-renders (one after each this.setState()) or only 1 re-render after the callback ends?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done, and this will result in 2 re-renders instead of 1. Usually there is no need to do this.

If `setState` are independent, it can be:

```
this.setState({ openA:true });
this.setState({ openB:false });
```

If updated states depend on each other, updater function should be used:

```
this.setState({ openA:true });
this.setState(state => ({ openB: !state.openA }));
```

Comment: In the case above the setState functions will be batched, But using funtional approach for setState will do it seperately?

Comment: completely understood, nice explanation. An upvote will help more :)

Comment: Two different setState may rerender twice, you can do it in a single setState `this.setState({ openA:true, openB: false });`  and for dependent values you have to use callback, since the setState is asynchronous, @estus mentioned answer will not work as expected, you have use the following method `this.setState({ openA:true }, ()=>this.setState({openB: this.state.openB}));`.

Comment: Above callback is only for demonstration, for Boolean values  you can set in single setState, use the above method only for complicated calculated values

Comment: your right, my mistake, I didn't know update function has that feature.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It will run it after the first setState is complete.

Comment: This is something I know, how will it act. the component update will be called after first set state or after second set state?